# Find all delimiters next to substring in string and replace in python

Tags: python, regex, search, replace

Sample string:

```
s = "<sec>John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary)</sec>"
```

I need to transform this to:

```
s = "<sec>John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary</sec>)"
```

This would need to work on both the start and end tag and for all delimiters like ".", ",", "-", "(", ")" and so on.

I could just do a search and replace for ")" and so on, but obviously I would like something a bit more sexy.

So basically move all delimiters outside the  tag.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below regex would help you to move  the delimiter which is present inside the opening and closing tag to the next of the closing tag.

```
(<sec>)([^.,()-]*)([.,()-])(<\/sec>)
```

REplacement string:

```
\1\2\4\3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yW3kF9/1)

```
>>> s = "<sec>John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary)</sec>"
>>> re.sub(r'(<sec>)([^.,()-]*)([.,()-])(<\/sec>)', r'\1\2\4\3', s)
'<sec>John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary</sec>)'
```

**OR**

This would work for any tags,

```
>>> s = "<sec>John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary)</sec>"
>>> re.sub(r'(<(\S+?\b)[^>]*>)([^.,()-]*)([.,()-])(<\/\2>)', r'\1\3\5\4', s)
'<sec>John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary</sec>)'
```

Answer (score 2):

An other regex variation:

```
>>> s = "Nicely<sec>, John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary)</sec>"
>>> re.sub(r'((?:<[^>]+>)?)( *[-.(),]+ *)((?:</[^>]+>)?)',r'\3\2\1',s)
#                           ^^        ^^
#                  move spaces with the punctuation
#                     remove that if not needed

'Nicely, <sec>John</sec> said hi to a woman (named <sec>Mary</sec>)'
```

The idea is to *swap* opening tags ↔ punctuation *or* punctuation ↔ closing tag.